# Query - Flot - Get x data value

Tags: jquery, html, charts, flot

I am using the plugin Flot in order to show a chart. I am implementing a tooltip in order to show the values x & y.

I have some problems getting the right values. The x axis are strings displaying a month name. How can I get the values from x axis ?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9x7aJ/5483/)

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
      var x = item.datapoint[0];
      var y = item.datapoint[1];
      $("#tooltip").html("x: " + x + " y: " + y)
        .css({
          top: item.pageY + 5,
          left: item.pageX + 5
        })
        .fadeIn(200);
    } else {
      $("#tooltip").hide();
   }    
});
```

Comment: Will this Fiddle work http://jsfiddle.net/jxbgmrjc/ ? try to click any point in the canvas

Comment: The Fiddle displays the position on the chart. I need to get the month name

Comment: Will this fiddle work? http://jsfiddle.net/jxbgmrjc/2/

Comment: Thank you so much.. thats solved my issue

Comment: I've created an answer please accept. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Display the month of the Bar please use the item.series.data

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {

    if (item) {

      var x = item.datapoint[0];
      var y = item.datapoint[1];

        var dataPoint = item.series.data[item.dataIndex];
        var mm = dataPoint[0]; 


      $("#tooltip").html("x: " + x + " y: " + y + " month: " + mm)
        .css({
          top: item.pageY + 5,
          left: item.pageX + 5
        })
        .fadeIn(200);
    } else {
      $("#tooltip").hide();
    }

  });
```

Comment: Thank you .. This is what I was looking for